# Transfer Multiple File problems via socket

Tags: java

Server side:

```
public class Server 
{
public static final String ALGORITHM = "RSA";
public static final String PRIVATE_KEY_FILE = "C:/Users/mrarsenal10/Desktop/server/key/private.key";
public static final String PUBLIC_KEY_FILE = "C:/Users/mrarsenal10/Desktop/server/key/public.key";
public static void generateKey() 
{
    try 
    {
        final KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
        keyGen.initialize(1024);
        final KeyPair key = keyGen.generateKeyPair();

        File privateKeyFile = new File(PRIVATE_KEY_FILE);
        File publicKeyFile = new File(PUBLIC_KEY_FILE);

    // Create files to store public and private key
        if (privateKeyFile.getParentFile() != null) {
            privateKeyFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        }
        privateKeyFile.createNewFile();

        if (publicKeyFile.getParentFile() != null) {
           publicKeyFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        }
        publicKeyFile.createNewFile();

        // Saving the Public key in a file
        ObjectOutputStream publicKeyOS = new ObjectOutputStream(
        new FileOutputStream(publicKeyFile));
        publicKeyOS.writeObject(key.getPublic());
        publicKeyOS.close();

        // Saving the Private key in a file
        ObjectOutputStream privateKeyOS = new ObjectOutputStream(
        new FileOutputStream(privateKeyFile));
        privateKeyOS.writeObject(key.getPrivate());
        privateKeyOS.close();
    }catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public static boolean areKeysPresent() 
{
    File privateKey = new File(PRIVATE_KEY_FILE);
    File publicKey = new File(PUBLIC_KEY_FILE);

    if (privateKey.exists() && publicKey.exists())
    {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
}
public static String decrypt(byte[] text, PrivateKey key) { // giải mã
    byte[] dectyptedText = null;
    try {
    // get an RSA cipher object and print the provider
    final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);

    // decrypt the text using the private key
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
    dectyptedText = cipher.doFinal(text);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new String(dectyptedText);
}
static void sendFile(Socket sock, String fName) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
{
    File transferFile = new File (fName);
    byte [] bytearray = new byte [(int)transferFile.length()]; 
    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(transferFile); 
    BufferedInputStream bin = new BufferedInputStream(fin); 
    bin.read(bytearray,0,bytearray.length); // luu  vao bytearray
    OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream(); // goi outputstream de
    System.out.println("Sending Files..."); 
    os.write(bytearray,0,bytearray.length); 
    os.flush();
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    if (!areKeysPresent()) {
        generateKey();
    }
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(15124); 
    Socket sock = serverSocket.accept();   
    sendFile(sock, PUBLIC_KEY_FILE);
    sendFile(sock, "lich.txt");
    sock.close();
}
}
```

Client side:

```
public class Client
{
public static final String ALGORITHM = "RSA";
public static final String PUBLIC_KEY_FILE = "C:/Users/mrarsenal10/Desktop/Client/public.key";
static void recvFile(Socket sock, String fName) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
{
    int filesize=1022386; 
    int bytesRead;
    int currentTot = 0;
    byte [] bytearray = new byte [filesize];
    InputStream is = sock.getInputStream(); 
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fName); 
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
    bytesRead = is.read(bytearray,0,bytearray.length); 
    currentTot = bytesRead; 
    do {
        bytesRead = is.read(bytearray, currentTot, (bytearray.length-currentTot));
        if(bytesRead >= 0) currentTot += bytesRead; } 
    while(bytesRead > -1);
    bos.write(bytearray, 0 , currentTot);
    bos.flush(); 
    bos.close();  
}
public static byte[] encrypt(String text, PublicKey key) {
    byte[] cipherText = null;
    try {
    // get an RSA cipher object and print the provider
    final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
    // encrypt the plain text using the public key
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    cipherText = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return cipherText;
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Socket sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1",15124);
    recvFile(sock, "public.key");
    recvFile(sock, "lich.txt");
    sock.close();
}
}
```

My problem is here  i just can send "public.key" or "lich.txt" from server to client, now i want to send  both "public.key" and "lich.txt". Thank for your help.

Comment: I've made some small edits to your question, but you should strongly consider rewording the question and reformatting it to make it easier for us to understand.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the overall design of both the Server and the Client.  On the server side it is sending two different files, but on the Client side it is just a stream of data.  There is no distinction between one byte representing data from one file vs the next.  So what is probably happening is you are calling recvFile, which receives ALL the data from BOTH files sent by the server.  After sending the data, the server closes the connection.  (You do this explicitly.)  So now, on the client side, you have an invalid socket.  However, you try to call recvFile again with the socket thinking that represents the second file.  This will lead to the SocketException or more likely OutOfBoundsException you are seeing.

To fix this, you need to add more hand-shaking between the Server and Client.  The simplest would be a delimiter representing the end of a file.  A better approach would be to append a known-size header to the front of every "message" (aka file) before sending any data which lets the client know the size of the file.  Then once the client receives the header it knows exactly how many bytes to read.

For now, to prevent the crash change you're `recvFile` method to something like this:

```
byte[] bytearray = new byte[4096];
InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fName);

int bytesRead;
while ((bytesRead = is.read(bytearray)) >= 0) {
    if (bytesRead > 0) {
        fos.write(bytearray, 0, bytesRead);
    }
}

fos.flush();
fos.close();
```